# Merge changes from remote github repository to your local repository

Tags: git, merge, repository, github

I have forked a repository on github some time ago, made a small change and pushed the change back to my github fork. The original repository has changed since. I would like to merge the changes from the original repository to my fork.

I am new to both git and github, and I need specific commands how to do it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
git remote add {name} {Public Clone URL}
git pull {name} master
git push
```

Example:

```
git remote add bret git://github.com/bret/watir.git
git pull bret master
git push
```

Answer (score 9):

```
git pull origin master
```

will do the job creating additional merge commit. If you do not have conflicts and do not want to create a rejoin (with additional 'merge' commit) for every commit that you push then `rebase` is more preferred. You can do it with the Git Gui+gitk. Just fetch remote with `Git Gui` then open history with `gitk` and create temporary `r_master` branch at `remotes/origin/master` fetched. Finally, call `git rebase r_master` in the `git bash`. This will place your commits on top of the remote modifications. You are ready to push and remove the `r_master`.

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559917/git-rebase-and-git-push-non-fast-forward-why-use/14276196#comment4955647_559971) suggests that there are shortcuts for this flow.

Answer (score 8):

Simply add original repo as a remote and merge your fork with it; then push merged fork to github.

There's also a [ruby gem for easier github operations](http://github.com/defunkt/github-gem/tree/master). You can merge upstream with one call...

Comment: I see that I forgot to add that I am new to git and github, and that I need specific commands how to do it.

Thanks for github-gem, but that is overkill for me.

Comment: in here people must use commands/code samples. words doesn't help on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8):

## **Syncing a fork**

*(from GitHub Help)*

https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork

Comment: Before we need to Configuring a remote for a fork: https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/