# How do I contribute to other's code in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I would like to contribute to a certain project in [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub). Should I **fork** it? **Branch** it? What is recommended and how to do it?

Comment: I wrote a more detailed step by step guide on contributing to Concrete5 on Github, but the process could apply to any project. [Check it out](https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/contributing-concrete5-github/).

Comment: check https://github.com/joindin/joind.in/wiki/How-to-Contribute-Code

Comment: perhaps with sufficient majority voting, a previously closed questions should be allowed to be resurrected again, and let people contribute to the thread again.

Comment: @wizztjh, Another easy tutorial: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-collaborate-on-github-open-source-projects

Comment: Here's a hands-on tutorial https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Ideally you:

1. [Fork](https://help.github.com/en/articles/fork-a-repo) the project
2. Make one or more well commented and clean commits to the repository. You can make a new branch here if you are modifying more than one part or feature.
3. Perform a [pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-pull-requests) in github's web interface.

if it is a new Feature request, don't start the coding first. Remember to post an issue to discuss the new feature.

If the feature is well discuss and there are some +1 or the project owner approved it, assign the issue to yourself, then do the steps above.

Some projects won't use the pull request system. Check with the author or mailing list on the best way to get your code back into the project.

Comment: Details on GitHub's [forking](http://help.github.com/forking/), and [pull requests](http://help.github.com/pull-requests/)

Comment: Yes, pull request. Merge request is gitorious terminology.

Comment: @MariusKavansky it's the other way round! Once you know what to work on, then only you contribute :)

Comment: after I contributed to some open source project. I think it is a better Idea to to open up an issue to discuss the new feature if it is a new feature. If it is a feature or issue that is well discussed, you should assign the issue to yourself then do the steps above. This is my 2cents.

Comment: @hashbrown, He's asking where's the "list" of requested features thus far. Those features that are already being requested and +1ed.

Comment: I did this and I ended up with a pull request on my own fork of the project instead of on the original author's project. So something is missing from the instructions.

Answer (score 34):

To add to [Yann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384776/how-do-i-contribute-to-others-code-in-github/4384824#4384824), once you have forked a project, you can develop in any branch you want (a new one, or one from the original project)

Remember to:

- add the original project as a remote (different form '`origin`', since `origin` would be your own repo, result of the fork)
- rebase your branch on top of the branch of the original repo you want to contribute.
  It is important your pulling request result in fast-forward merges.
  See for instance:

  - "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".
  - "[Update of forked repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199389/6309)"
  - "[Git working fork with updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23285782/6309)"

Comment: can you add details or links on your second point *(rebasing branch)*?

Comment: @JorgeArtware I have updated the answer with a few links illustrating the rebase.

Comment: @VonC I ask a question here but if you believe it is necessary, I will make a whole new question out of it.
Why would I rebase instead of merge, other than having the 'straight history' ? In other words, here's what I do when I contribute to some projects (after the PR from my feature branch has been merged to develop and to master branches): 
`git checkout master;`
`git pull;`
same for develop (where my feature branch was merged first)
The difference I can think of, after reading "pull vs pull --rebase" and "merge vs rebase" is just the flat history. Anything else more deep?

Comment: @grasshopper in term of "contribution" (the context of this page), you always want to rebase your local commits on top of updated branches before pushing: that will make said contribution trivial to integrate by the maintainer to the original project branch. In the context of your question, where your PR has been accepted, sure, you can merge instead of rebase to update existing branches.

Comment: (Sorry changed username just now to reflect my github) - @VonC thank you, so all the suggestions that I was reading about the rebase apply before the PR, makes sense. To reflect the accepted and merged PR inside my local repo, is there any common practice (rebase instead of merge), or can I do whatever? What if I will submit another PR though?

Comment: @linuxbandit The thing is: if you are talking about an internal development you don't intent to contribute back, you can rebase or merge, as you want. For another wip (work in progress) that will be contributed back, a rebase on top of upstream is preferable, as Jon Skeet himself explained an hour ago in https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/917#issuecomment-289007696.

Answer (score 15):

To add to Yan and VonC's answers, this is a good resource from github themselves: http://help.github.com/forking/

Also be sure to look on the right sidebar under the "collaborating" heading.

Answer (score 10):

There is a great Railscast video [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/300-contributing-to-open-source) that walks you through the process.  It also has a number of good tips such as showing how to determine which branch you might want to work on when contributing, using tests, submodules, etc.

While this screencast is primarily focused on Rails developers most of the information is valid for contributing to any open source project.

Answer (score 4):

Github has many ways of collaborating to a project. The model most project use is a pull request model. I've started a project to help people making their first GitHub pull request. You can do the hands-on tutorial to [make your first PR here](https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions/blob/master/README.md)

The workflow is simple as

- Fork the repo in github
- Clone the repo to your machine
- Make a branch and make necessary changes
- Push your changes to your fork on GitHub `git push origin branch-name`
- Go to your fork on GitHub to see a `Compare and pull request` button
- Click on it and give necessary details

Answer (score 3):

lornajane has a blog post that explains the process well:
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2010/contributing-to-projects-on-github

Answer (score 2):

## Technical workflow

I would suggest the following workflow:

1. Fork the repository (via GitHub web interface: "Fork" button)
2. In your forked repository, copy the URL
3. Clone (in the command line)

   `git clone <url-from-your-workspace>`
4. Enter the directory, that just got created, and create a branch

   `cd <directory>
   git checkout -b <branchname>`
5. Now make your changes
6. You can create one or more commits after each change:

   `git add .;`
   `git commit`
7. When done, push your changes

   `git push origin <branch>`
8. In your command line, you should [see a URL to create the PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52375419/github-pull-request-link-when-pushing-branch). Visit the URL and click the button to create a PR.
9. If not, visit the repository in the browser and it will offer you a button for creating the pull request

That's it.

So, basically, you forked the repository to your workspace, created a new branch and pushed that new branch.

If you later make more PR from the same cloned repo, you should synchronize (get the latest changes from the original repository) before you create another branch for another PR:

```
git checkout master
git remote add upstream <url-of-original-repo>
git pull upstream master
```

## Other considerations:

- the project may have Contribution Guidelines: Look for a file CONTRIBUTING.rst or .md
- you may want to follow the coding guidelines for the project
- you may want to outline your idea as issue first
- you may want to look at the Pull Requests tab for the project and check if there are open PR, merged PR

These suggestions are here to save you from the trouble of putting work into a PR that will not get merged. If there is activity in the project and PR get merged, this is a good sign. If there are Contribution Guidelines, follow them.

Always be courteous. Remember, the maintainers of the project are in no way obligated to merge your PR. Do you have something valuable to add to the project?