# Syncing my fork causes the commits to appear in pull requests

Tags: git, github

So I fork a repo, the repo then has new commits. I update my fork with `git fetch upstream` and `git merge upstream/master`. Now lets say I make a change after this and submit a pull request. Those previously merged commits appear in the pull request. How do I not make this happen? I'm tired of having to delete the fork and re-fork so that my pull requests are clean.

Comment: The answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/14821583/758446 lead me to believe there is no way to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Well that sucks. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want having merge commits, try `git rebase`. It wipes all you work and reapplies all you changes ahead. But note that your commits will become different.

Comment: If this is the taken approach, I think the `git pull upstream/master --rebase` could be used in place of the fetch/merge no?

Comment: I want my fork to remain in sync with the repo. I'm not making changes for itself, just for pull requests.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand you. But `rebase` will help you to keep you fork up to date and also avoid merge commits. @BlackVegetable already mentioned exact command.

Comment: Also, it's not only merge commits. Here's another example: my pull request is accepted. If I sync my fork, when I make a commit and submit a pull request, the previous commits from the previous pull request appear in the pull request in addition to my new commit. The only solution I have is deleting the fork and re-forking, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: And `rebase` will help you in this situation :) It keeps your history linear. Just give it a try.

Comment: I tried it and have the same problem. Any commits to the repo from after I forked appear in my pull request. No merge commits.