# github - How to fork inside a repository (Into an submodule)

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-fork

I have a repository, let's call "School's Projects".
My friend have a repository, let's call "Foo Project".
I've created a submodule inside my "School's Projects" with "Foo Project".
The thing is I want to edit "Foo Project" and create pull requests from it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to fork the "Foo Project" repo into your github account firstly as I presume you don't have write access to the original "Foo Project" repo on github.

As submodules work exactly the same as any other git repo simply go into this directory and add a new remote for your own fork of "Foo Project". Do your edits, commit and push to your fork remote.

Then goto github and goto your fork and then look for pull request, [instructions are on github](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) so I wont repeat.

Comment: No way to do that without forking the repo to my github?

Comment: You can if you have access to the original repo to create branches but this is usually down to the owner of that repo giving you access. This has been covered in another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821583/pull-request-without-forking