# Update of forked repository on github

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have forked a repository from github - it's called bootstrap.

I've cloned my fork:

```
git clone https://github.com/Fowowski/bootstrap.git
```

The bootstrap project has a master branch and a 3.0.0-wip branch - ill be working on 3.0.0-wip

So next thing I do (since im on master and its a 2.3.x stable) is switch to 3.0.0-wip and add a remote:

```
git checkout 3.0.0-wip
git remote add upstream https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git
```

and now im making some changes in the 1 file... after few days when I finished I realised that there were some changes in the 3.0.0-wip and my forked repository is no longer actual.

How should I update my forked repository to make it as clean as it may only be for pushing it in pull request? I heard that I should do fetch/rebase.

I did `pull` via tortoise git one time and after I pushed there were few commits that wasnt mine in my pull request... - you can see it here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7641#commits-pushed-2eb9053 - Im assuming that I didnt do something important but dunno really what.

I did some research about my issue and I found that I should probably run:

```
git fetch upstream

git merge upstream/master

git push
```

My problem is - and thats the part that I dont understand most about git: git merge upstream/master - I cant do merge upstream/master because master is bootstrap 2.3.x not 3.0.0-wip? Am I missreading this command or what?

Could you please tell me how can I properly update my forked repository via git bash? What are the proper steps that I need to run after I changed files in my cloned fork repository?

Answer (score 0):

The fetch / rebase idea is good, especially if you don't have pushed already your work:

```
git fetch
# Assuming you are in the right 3.0.0-wip
git rebase upstream/3.0.0.-wip
```

You could even do it quicker with a [`pull --rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/git-pull-vs-git-fetch-git-rebase):

```
git pull --rebase upstream
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that instead of `git merge upstream/master` you should do

```
git merge upstream/3.0.0-wip
```

(BTW, as you have been advised, it is probably a better idea to do a `git rebase`)