# How to patch code in someone else's project hosted on github

Tags: git, github

I have cloned someone's open source code hosted on github and made some changes to fix things on various platforms. I'd like to feed this back into the system. How do I contribute this into github so that others get the benefits?

Comment: For hopefully obvious reasons, you cannot do this yourself, at least not in someone else's repo. What you can do depends on the project. Most of the larger projects have something like a "How to contribute" section in their documentation. Does your project have anything like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I contribute to other's code in GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384776/how-do-i-contribute-to-others-code-in-github)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you want to create a **Pull Request**.

1. Push your fixes to a branch of your fork on GitHub
2. Visit the GitHub page of the original project
3. Click on **Pull Requests**, it's somewhere in the top-right
4. Click on **New pull request**
5. Click on **compare across forks**
6. Select your own fork + branch
7. Review the differences. Make sure it's clean.
8. Create the pull request, and maybe get in touch with the maintainers

**UPDATE**

If you don't have your fork on GitHub yet, then you have to create that first:

1. Go to the project's page on GitHub
2. Click on **Fork**, it's somewhere in the top-right
3. Clone your fork to your PC
4. Make your changes and commit (you can split to multiple smaller commits, it's actually better)
5. Push your local branch back to GitHub
6. Now your fork on GitHub has your changes, ready create a **Pull Request** from it, as explained above.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are contributor:**

1. Create your own branch using `git branch [branch_name]`
2. Make your changes in the code of that branch
3. If you have added new files you will need the `git add .`(adds all the new files) command to notify GIT of your new files. After this GIT will start tracking the new file.
4. Commit the changes `git commit -am "Commit message"`
5. Push your changes using `git push origin [branch_name]`

PS: You are not allowed to make changes to the main branch(called **master**) on a public repository unless you are a contributor.

After this the admin will check the changes you have made and if he approves they will be merged with the **master** branch.

**If you are not a contributor:**

Create a pull request as suggested by @janos

I'm not sure if you are looking for a GIT tutorial but here is one to start with anyway.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html

Comment: Usually you can't push to the remote repo at all unless you've given permissions. That applies to all branches. Also, one can send pull requests for any branch, not just master.

Answer (score 0):

In github, you can send a pull request to patch code in someone else's project. I've started a project to help people making their first GitHub pull request. You can do the hands-on tutorial to [make your first PR here](https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions/blob/master/README.md)

The workflow is simple as

- Fork the repo in github..
- Clone the repo to your local machine.
- Make a branch for changes and make necessary changes
- Push your changes to your fork on GitHub `git push origin branch-name`
- Go to your fork on GitHub to see a `Compare and pull request` button
- Click on it and give necessary details