# Git working fork with updates

Tags: git, github

I wonder if the following scenario is possible with Git.

I forked someone's repository.

I do want to work on my own copy of the repository with getting updates from the initial repository.

Occasionally, I do want to release my code and send pull request to initial repository.

I am not sure if this possible, if yes please describe shortly what should I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but a couple of best-practices would involve:

- doing your modification in your own branch (that you can push to your fork)
- updating the branches common with the original repo with a `git fetch upstream` (upstream being the name of a remote referencing the original repo you forked)
- rebasing your own branch on top of the updated original branch:
  (See "[`git fork` is `git clone`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309)")

  ```
  git checkout myBranch
  git rebase upstream/master
  ```
- if you do a PR, try to make it a small one (with a few commits in it), focus on a specific feature, rather than doing a large one, with many commits and many changes in it.

See more at "[couples tips on pull requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by following these steps:

1. Work on your cloned forked repository (on your local machine). Typically you would clone from your cloned repository so that you can push to it
2. Push to this repo (`origin` will be the forked repository, while your local branch will be tracked by `master`) - `git push origin master`
3. File a pull request to the repo from which you forked - follow [this link](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request)

You can read up more on the [github documentation](https://help.github.com/) for further details