# How can I update npm package on github

Tags: node.js, github, npm

How can I update any npm packages on github? If version dependencies of this package is outdated. I am not owner this packages but I my platform works with this npm packages and when I update my nodejs version to last, I will get error.

**This commands I used for update nodejs**

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs

rm -rf /niode_modules

npm install
```

This works nice but after updating nodejs some npm packages stopped working with new version

Comment: Are you asking how to contribute to existing projects?

Comment: @TimCastelijns yes I need to update dependencies for ensure work my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I contribute to other's code in GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384776/how-do-i-contribute-to-others-code-in-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly upgrade someone else's package.
Here's what you CAN do:

1. If you have a fix you can fork their github repo, make the changes and send the author a pull request. But I don't think you have the fix.
2. You can request the author to provide support for latest nodejs.
3. You can report issue on the github repo about whatever error you are getting after upgrading nodejs.

If you want to do the 1st option, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384776/how-do-i-contribute-to-others-code-in-github) post can help