# How to create a git pull request on a public github repository

Tags: git, github, pull-request

There is a public github repository to which I want to create a pull request. I have a project on my local machine that I need to check in and send it to them for review. I have tried the following and failed

```
git clone public repo
# create new branch
# add code in the branch 
git add/commit changes to this new branch 
git push
```

When I do the git push I enter my github account credentials and it fails. I know that this should fail because I don't have access to their repo but what I am doing wrong? Do I need to create some sort of an account with them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You first have to fork the project :

[image]

Then you can work on your version of the code.

You will finally push your branch to your repository and then you will be able to create a pull request on the main project.

You can find extra info here: [Fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) or [Contribute to someone's repository](http://kbroman.org/github_tutorial/pages/fork.html)

PS: Related to [How do I contribute to other's code in GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384776/how-do-i-contribute-to-others-code-in-github)