# Github pull request link when pushing branch

Tags: git, github

When I pushed a branch to my remote on github it was giving me the message:

```
remote: Create a pull request for 'branch-name' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/repo/pull/new/branch-name
```

which was really nice to have that clickable link. It is no longer giving me that link, how can I get it back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly recent (sept. 2018) [and is described as](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-09-10-pull-request-url-output-in-the-command-line/):

> When you **push a new branch to GitHub** from the command line, you’ll now notice a URL within the output which you can copy in order to quickly open a new pull request.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/45141/45300188-f6865080-b50d-11e8-9a82-866c9d7e9546.png]

So this is when you are pushing a *new* branch, not when you are pushing new commits to an existing branch.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this, makes me think something went wrong. Any idea if this can be turned off?

Comment: @BrandonBil Not sure: that comes from the remote side, that is GitHub: only their support (https://github.com/contact) can know if there is an option to make that message go away.

Comment: `https://github.com/$userRepo/compare/$base...$branch?expand=1` will specify the base branch (target) for the PR. (Where are these different URLs defined?)

Comment: @JoeBowbeer They are specified by the contributor when he/she defines and make a new PR.

Comment: I'm a fan of this message, but I'd like to be able to enable it for every push to a branch. I guess that isn't possible?

Comment: @zymhan It doesn't look possible at the moment, since it is only for new branches, not for commits pushed on existing branches.

Comment: Any idea how to turn it on for github self host? -- and while on the subject, to show the link of the PR if it already exists?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Considering this URL is created when you are pushing a *new* branch, I doubt the URL would already exist. Regarding GHE (GitHub for Enterprise, the "self-hosted" GitHub instance), I don't know.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Found it: https://enterprise.github.com/releases/2.15.0/notes, this is included with GHE 2.15 from Oct. 2018: "Pull request URL is included in the output of a git push."

Comment: ```So this is when you are pushing a new branch, not when you are pushing new commits to an existing branch.``` Is it possible to show the URL every time you push new commits to your branch as well?

Comment: @Olshansk Not that I know of. You can display the PR your branch is currently associated with, using [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view).

Comment: Gitlab (not Github) will, in every push message, give you a link to create a new PR, or, if one already exists, the link to it. It's simple, intuitive, and a huge timesaver.

Comment: @ent I agree. From what I wrote above, GitHub does it too, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I usually just check out a new branch, and then push the new branch up. Get the URL from the message, and use it create a PR for the new branch. Then, I delete the old one (both local, and remote).