# How to create a Pull Request on github via cli?

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I have a repository on github and have created a branch. I am able to create a new local repository on my machine and clone from the main repository.

I now want to make some changes to the code and push to the main repository.

I have run through the steps, `git status` to check files, `git add .`, `git commit -m ""`, and finally `git push origin <branch_name>`.

How do I make a pull request via the command line to the main branch of my repository so that a pull request can be seen for the main branch?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request

Comment: Also on your first push, git should print a link to the create a pull request page if your config is setup properly: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52375419/457268

Comment: I ahve the URL hwo do i use it to make a pull rewquest to the main branch of the repo?

Comment: I want to do this from the command line btw

Comment: Use the [github cli](https://cli.github.com/)

Comment: Okay and then how do i make a pull request?

Comment: If you login in the cli via `gh auth login` you can create a PR via  `gh pr create`

Comment: Consider reading [the github cli documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create)?

Comment: Thank u bois xxxx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+command+line+pull+request

Answer (score 0):

For the github's web interface, it's pretty straighforward and explained at best from their docs:

[Creating a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/creating-a-pull-request).

---

Yet since you said you want to create the PR via the cli, you also need to install the official github cli:

https://cli.github.com/

After installation for your OS you need to authenticate:

```
gh auth login
```

You have different options, I'd say the ssh is the most developer-friendly approach. You also have to provide an authentication token, yet the prompts are self-explantory.

When you then are inside your git checkout folder, you can then create a pull request for your currently checked out branch via:

```
gh pr create
```

For further details, see [gh's docs about pr creation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create).