# How can I create forks on Github

Tags: github

I am new to Github and I do not know how to use it well, however, I need to create forks and I don't know where to begin

I tried to contribute to someone else's project but it did not create a fork for me and I was unable to download the others persons readMe file

Comment: You click fork at the top right...

Comment: I don't think this is a coding question. Consider reading github's documentation https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo

Comment: What docs have you read? What search did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4384776/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+how+to+fork

Answer (score 1):

First up you'll want to go to the repository you want to fork on GitHub. Once you've found it you'll find a little "fork" menu in the top right corner. You click the little arrow and click "Create new fork".
You now have your very own fork of the project!