# Best Practice when Forking a Repo on Github to Start Your Own

Tags: git, github

There is a repo on github that I would like to build off of.  What is the best practice for doing this?  Here is what I've done:

1) Fork the repo.
2) Start a new repo.
3) Change the forked repo's remote origin url to the new repo.
4) Push the new repo's local copy to github.

This gives me a 'starting point' for the new repo, however, I still have the original repo's commit history etc.  What's the best practice /etiquette for keeping things like this (as opposed to deleting the commit history & starting from scratch.)

The original author will get full credit regardless on what I do, but it seems the commit history might confuse folks who want to use my repo.

Comment: Why would the commit history confuse people?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm rather green when it comes to git / github, but the forked repo looks identical to the origin (which, essentially, it is).  Once I start adding features / code, it will be different, but the commit history will be the same.  Is it something that is expected?  What is the normal workflow for these types of things?

Comment: The history shows who made the commits. It's only polite that you don't erase the history (and make it look like you're the only contributor).

Comment: @Juhana Right, that makes sense.  I think I've determined what I need to do.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Once I start adding features / code, it will be different, but the commit history will be the same. Is it something that is expected?

Yes, but the true idea behind the fork is the possibility for you to contribute back to the `upstream` repo (i.e. the repo you have forked on GitHub side), through [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

That is why you usually don't just change the url of origin to the new repo, you also register a remote repo '`upstream`' referring to the original repo you have forked.

[image: fork]

The other idea, even if you don't contribute back, is to keep up with any evolution from `upstream`: you can `git fetch upstream`, and merge or rebase whatever new commits from upstream you want.

Comment: Your last comment is probably the one thing that people fail to do and then never have their commits added back upstream. Most projects will want you to rebase your commits ontop of the latest upstream commits before they'll even take a look at your pull request. Its extra work for the maintainers if they have to do the possible de-conflicting of rebasing ontop of the latest upstread `HEAD`.

Comment: I understand forking, fixing and doing a pull request (to an extent.)  This makes sense to me if you're actively building features for, or fixing bugs in, the original repo.  What if I want to add a super-specific feature for a niche audience that requires the use of the original repo, but doesn't necessarily fit in to its normal use case?  Is forking the wrong thing to do?

Comment: @DanB. no, because of the last sentence of my answer: forking will allow you to keep a strong link between the `upstream` repo and your fork. Arguably, you could do the same (pull from `upstream` in order to keep up with latest `upstream` modifications) without a fork, but it is best to clearly mention where your GitHub repo comes from. The fork makes it very visible, even though you won't make any pull request back to `upstream`.

Comment: @VonC I understand. Thank you! (I misread the last sentence before.)