# How do I have my project specific files inside a git submodule?

Tags: php, git, cakephp, twig, git-submodules

I have a cakephp project. Let us call it Project *Super*.

It has its own github repo.

*Super* has git submodule that pulls from this repo. https://github.com/predominant/TwigView

The issue is that I need to have my own project specific extensions, so I need to create new files in the Lib folder of https://github.com/predominant/TwigView and I need to add require_once statements inside the file View/TwigView.php of https://github.com/predominant/TwigView

I want to maintain the git submodule as much as I can.

I know I can fork the https://github.com/predominant/TwigView and add the project specific extension files and changes.

*Super* would then have this forked version as git submodule.

However, I am not pleased with that because that means

1. it is slightly harder to update the forked version from its upstream
2. I need to have 1 forked version per project.

What would be the cleanest, and easily maintainable way to use https://github.com/predominant/TwigView as a git submodule in Project *Super* and other cakephp projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. no, it should be that much harder to update your forked project.
   If you just add upstream (original `TwigView` repo) as a remote, you can pull any changes from upstream to your local submodule, and push back to your fork.
   (as described in "[Pull new updates for forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-for-forked-github-repository/3903835#3903835)")
   Granted, it is slightly harder, but is the recommended workflow.
2. Why one fork per repo?
   The idea behind a fork is to gain publication privileges (you can push to a fork because you own it).
   Why not push to a branch-per-project within the unique `TwigView` fork?