# Store git repo in a repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repo that I save to bitbucket, which stores my project. For this project I'm relying on several tools such as Bootstrap. Inside my repo I cloned the Bootstrap repo and made some local edits, but it's not being picked up, how can I store a repo in a repo?

Comment: Shouldn't the question rather be how to make the edits apply instead?

Comment: Sounds like a job for http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: submodules sound great, but that doesnt make it save the files to my own repo

Answer (score 1):

[Submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) is the answer, except you would need to reference a [***fork*** of the Bootstrap repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309) instead of the original Bootstrap repo, since you need to have to make modifications in it.

You can fork a Bitbucket repo, but, in the off chance that Bootstrap isn't on Bitbucket, you can simply clone it locally, and push it back on an empty Bootstrap repo created by you on Bitbucket.