# Merge two github repositories and make a pull request

Tags: git, github

I've forked a repo. I've made some commits to my repo and made a 1st pull request. They where already merged into original repo. Now I added more commits and I want to make a 2nd pull request.

There are two problems:

1. Original repo was modified and I don't have this changes in my repo. I tried to make a fetch from the URL of the original repo (with Tortoise Git), but that didn't seem to work (there was nothing to commit after that).
2. I'm unable to create a pull request with anything other then was already pulled.

Would like to use Tortoise Git for that, but I can use git command line if I must ;-).

[image: commits and branches]

Legend:

- green boxes are revisions that were already pushed to original repo.
- red boxes are revisions that I want to push to original repo.
- number 4 is the one I should merge into my repo.

PS: I've read about [branching and merging on git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), but that seem to be about merging and branching in a single repo.

EDIT: This seem to answer my first problem: [Pull new updates from original GitHub repository into forked GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository?rq=1) I'm not sure if I were supposed to do merge or rebase in this case, though...

Comment: I'd go with a rebase if possible; that will make your pull request a bit cleaner. (It won't have any stray merge commits in it.)

Comment: But would that mean 5,6,7,8 would be a single revision? I'm not sure I want that.

Comment: No that's not what a rebase does. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Thanks, but bottom section makes me want to stick to merging ;-). It seems more clear to me. I'll probably rebase next time before I make my own commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
git fetch original
git rebase original/master
git push origin master
```

(with '`original`' being the name of the remote referring to the original repo url.
'upstream' would be a better name, since it wouldn't be so close to '`origin`')
(if you already pushed your master branch, you would need to do a `git push --force origin master`)

See "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)";

[image: upstream vs. fork]

Your pull request will be **automatically updated** (no need to "redo" a pull request).

But please: **always make your pull request in a branch, not in master**: see "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)".
`master` should reflect *exactly* what is in upstream ('`original`') `master`.

Comment: So basically if work on anything new I should create a branch for it? Seems kind of strange, wouldn't that be an overkill?

Comment: @Nux if you want on anything new that is candidate for a pull request. In that case, it isn't overkill. If it is specific to your fork only (no pull request), then you can use one branch if you want.