# Possible workflow with git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

I would like to use swagger (https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui) as part of my project. Using swagger requires editing one file. Can I add a submodule and make edits to certain files, commits and push to my public repo instead of upstream?

I used to use subtrees for that but out of a sudden subtrees stopped to work (another issue, identical to https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather **fork** `wordnik/swagger-ui`, and declare that fork as a submodules.

That way, I can:

- make edit within that submodule, add, commit and push to my fork
- go back to the parent repo, add and commit in order to record the new SHA1 of my submodule.
- in my submodule, I can fetch the original repo `wordnik/swagger-ui`, and rebase my own branch on top of '`upstream/master`', in order to keep up-to-date with the latest evolutions.
  (as described in "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)")

Comment: In retrospective it's obvious. I thought I can somewhat prevent forking when changing only one file.