# How to update my new branch in a forked github repo

Tags: github, branch

I forked a public repo on github to do some changes. I created a new branch and implemented my changes there. Now I want to get the new commits from the upstream repo, but I was just able to sync the upstream commits to my master repo not to the new branch. How do I sync from upstream to my new branch instead of master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I sync from upstream to my new branch instead of master?

You are supposed to sync `master` first, then rebase your branch on top of the newly updated `master`.

```
git pull upstream master
git checkout yourBranch
git rebase master
git push -f origin yourBranch
```

That supposes you have a remote named '`upstream`' referring to the url of the original repo (that you have forked)

See "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)" for the "`git remote add upstream`" command example.