# Questions On Github

Tags: android, git, github

I am starting with android Rom development.
The original author of the sources have uploaded it on github
As of now i have used the repo tool of google to sync it from github to my local machine

How can i fork that repo without downloading it again?

Should i just go into that directory and execute after forked from github website?

```
$ git clone https://github.com/username/repo-name.git'
```

I cannot try it since the repo is still being synced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

- rename the initial url remote name into upstream

  ```
  git remote rename origin upstream
  ```
- add a new origin:

  ```
  git add origin https://YourLogin@github.com/YourLogin/yourFork
  ```

That way, you can still keep track of the original repo while pushing to your fork.

To illustrate that update process, see:

- "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)"
- "[How to update my new branch in a forked github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22420523/6309)"
- "[Official Github Tutorial (online virtual tutorial)](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can change git repo remote address

for example:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin  git_forked_repo_address
```

Comment: you mean 
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin MY-Forked-Repo-Address ??