# Git forking creation

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have a few questions about 'forking' a repo in which I am slightly confused about it, even after reading the documentations. 
Really appreciated if someone could guide me through and pardon me my english and understanding in Git.

I am using Atlassian, and say I am going to copy this repo called 'testProj' which is under the projects called 'allProjects'

1. First, can I do a fork through terminal commands, like git clone etc? Otherwise is it only do-able through the web ui?
2. From my understanding via their [docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+forks+in+Stash), supposedly I have created the fork as stated, will the creator of that repo be notified with email etc.?
3. Prior to Qns 2, the original repo is displayed as / - `allProjects/testProj`. In the 'forked' repo, it appeared as / - `guest01/testProj`, so does this means that it is using my username as the project name, while containing the new repo?
4. Should I git clone the repo in my username, `ssh://git@stash/~guest01/testProj.git` will it affects in the future, if I did a `git pull` or `git fetach -all` to update the branches whether or not in the first place did I enable or not enable the `Enable Fork Syncing` option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, can I do a fork through terminal commands, like git clone etc? Otherwise is it only do-able through the web ui?

Yes, it is a clone on the server side, so it is an operation only started through the server web ui.

> From my understanding via their docs, supposedly I have created the fork as stated, will the creator of that repo be notified with email etc.?

No

> guest01/testProj, so does this means that it is using my username as the project name, while containing the new repo?

A fork is done under a user account to allow that user to clone/pull/push a repo he/she would otherwise *not* be permitted to contribute back to (push back).

> Should I git clone the repo in my usernam

If you don't select [fork syncing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Keeping+forks+synchronized), then you would need to add a reference to the original repo (usually named "upstream") and do a fetch upstream yourself, rebasing your work on top of the updated upstream remote tracking branches.

See "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)" as an example of a manual sync.

The fork syncing mechanism does all that for you.

Comment: Thank you for the informative sharing. Prior to Qns 2, say in the repo, there are 2 branches, Master and Develop, and I push the changes onto the Develop (in the fork repo) and created a pull request (adding in the creator of the repo as reviewer), wouldn't this be about the same as doing a normal 'pushed' repo procedure since it is committing the changes to the same branch? I hope my phrasing is making sense...

Comment: @yan yes, except you haven't the right to push to the original repo. And don't modify existing branches: always make your modification on custom branches started from the original branches: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309

Comment: That makes sense, that the creator should be the one to push the changes etc as I am the one that is modifying his/her project. Lastly, can I ask are there any other things that I should look out for while doing the 'fork', or exercises that I can use? I am still pretty new to it and ain't having on hand projects for me to try out...

Comment: @yan sure: that is why I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309: my answer and the other answers on that page are helpgul when it comes to forks.