# Troubleshooting the workflow to incorporate upstream changes into forked repo

Tags: git

I forked a git repo, and then created  a branch called "strlen."

After submitting a PR and making suggested changes: .

The following was my attempt to merge in upstream changes:

Part A: fetch and merge from upstream:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

Part B: squash the upstream commits, retaining only a single commit comment for my particular changes:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

> Note: for the interactive part, I did a s(quash) on all of the commits
>   except for the latest one (mine) at the top.

Part C: push the changes back to my fork on github:

```
 git push origin strlen
```

The "squash" did not seem to do as advertised this time: all of the intervening commits **as well as the intervening file changes ** are visible on the strlen branch. The new Pull Request shows everything, whereas the intention was to display only *my* file changes.

So , any hints on

- (a) should I have performed the rebase somewhat differently
- or (b) take another approach altogether

**UPDATE**  From VonC's great answer, I added some more details and here is the current solution:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/foo/bar.git
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git checkout strlen
# Make changes. If using IJ you can then create CL and commit the CL locally.
#   Alternatively simply use command line and do commit -m "Made some updates"
git rebase -i upstream/master  # Squash the newer commits into 
                               # the original one used to create the PR
git push -f origin
```

The above workflow worked really well. Well enough in fact to fix the problems (merge errors) caused by my original workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't merge `upstream/master` when updating a PR branch.

You rebase your local PR branch on top of the updated `upstream/master`:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout strlen
git rebase -i upstream/master # you can squash if you want there
git push -f origin
```

You force the push, but your PR will be updated automatically, taking into account the new history of the `strlen` branch.

See more at:

- "[couple tips for PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)" and
- "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".

Comment: Thx for another git tidbit.

Comment: This worked SO well that it succesfully cleaned up the mess resulting from the attempted workflow in the OP.

Comment: I updated the OP with a somewhat enhanced version of your solution. Thanks much for the tips.