# Is possible to add files inside a submodule folder to the parent GIT repository?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have one GIT repository:
my_git_repo
and I added a submodule: 
my_git_repo\submodule
That is OK, now:

Is possible to add files (and change ?) to submodule but keep the tracking in the parent "my_git_repo" repository?

All I want is to be able to update the submodule but still make some changes and additions on my own.

Ideas or suggestions ? Any other way to do it nicely?

Comment: I would like to be able to add a subfolder to a submodule, and track the subfolder in the parent repository without modifying the submodule repo. My specific use case is a third party submodule with source code for a library. I want to build the library and store the `submodule/lib` folder in the parent repo, while ignoring it in the child repo. Pretty sure this isn't supported though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is possible to add files (and change ?) to submodule but keep the tracking in the parent "my_git_repo" repository?

Yes, but for each new commit you will make in the submodule, you will need to:

- push those commit to the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) of that submodule (the repo which this submodule is the clone of)
- go back to the parent repo, `git add` and `git commit` (because the gitlink will have changed, [gitlink being the special entry in the index which records the SHA1 of the submodule repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)).

The second step doesn't have to be done for *every* commit done in the submodule, but it will have to be done eventually, in order to record the next stable state of the submodule.

---

If the submodule is a public repo, then you need to fork it ([GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo), [BitBucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+Repository)), and change it remote 'origin':

```
cd /path/to/submodule
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin /url/of/the/fork
```

Then you can push to the submodule repo.

To update the submodule repo with new commits coming from the original repo (that you have forked), see "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)"

[image]

Comment: But I don't manage the "submodule" repository. It is a public repository. So I cannot push it.

Comment: @KammutierSpule but you can fork it, and then you can push. I have edited my answer to describe the process.

Comment: @VonC but if he fork it it will be separate repository and he will need to handle updtaes manually from official repo to forked one.

Comment: @MichaelA. Agreed: I just illustrated that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562274/6309