# How to contribute to a project you've forked?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I've forked https://github.com/user/proj.git and done significant development on (the master branch of) my fork.

I want to work on a problem that upstream is having (that I have not fixed in my fork).  If I've understood correctly, I should create a feature branch off of upstream's last checkin on their master:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout upstream/master
git checkout -b my_new_feature
```

the second of those commands lets me know that I'm in 'detached HEAD' state.. is that anything I need to be concerned with (understand to do this task)?

Now I do my changes, then `git add` and `git commit` the changed files, then `git push` to github, but when I create a pull request I'm told that my pull request can't be automatically merged because there is a conflict between a change I've done and a change that was checked into `upstream/master` after I did my `git fetch`.

The conflicting changes are semantically equivalent, so I want to defer to `upstream/master`'s version. How do I rebase (that is what I want to do, right?) my pull request off of `upstream/master` while resolving the conflict? (I'm well versed in Subversion and a newbie in git if that helps in answering..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this pull request that is problematic, since it includes a conflict with changes done to upstream/master after I branched off of it
>
> the steps needed to "provide him a proper rebased branch"?

A "proper rebased branch" means a branch rebased on top of `upstream/master` (with upstream being the name of the original repo that you have forked)

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout myBranch
git rebase upstream/master
```

(I also describe that step in "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)")

You can also do a rebase interactive, if you want to clean-up a bit the history of your branch (`git rebase -i`)

That way, you resolve any conflict in your local clone, and `git push --force` your branch to your fork.
If you had already a PR (pull request) in progress, it will update itself in order to take into account the revised history of your rebased branch.

The goal remains for the maintainer of the original project to merge your branch in his/her master branch, and do so with a trivial merge (0 conflict).

Answer (score 1):

To complete Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's answer and comment:

Before all, you should provide the maintainer a painless merge, which means being up to date regarding the master branch.

When a maintainer merges a pull requests he can choose to ways:

- Squash it into one commit.
- Merge the pull request tree as a whole.

On the first option, the size/comments/separation of the commits is not important since everything will be one commit commented by the maintainer.

On the second option, each commit of your branch is important. So each commit must represent a logical unit of work (for example, you should not have commits fixing bugs you introduced with your branch, or commits that result in non functionnal project). You can always push force your pull request branch to make it pretty.

Concerning being up to date on the master branch you should apply the same logic. Commits "Merge master into Pipo" are not usefull at all, you should rebase you branch to make the "merge" invisible.

And last but not least, every maintainer has its own habits, so if code, test and documentation are always commited seperatly or grouped you should do the same. Anyway when you post a pull request if the maintainer finds something to tell about it you can discuss it with him and change it the way he considers well to be merged.

Comment: What would be the steps to rebase my branch when there is a conflict?

Comment: @thebjorn the ones I described in my answer: the goal is to detect the conflict in your local clone instead of being told by the maintainer of the original repo that there is a conflict (when he/she attempts to merge your PR in the original repo)

Answer (score 0):

When you fork a project on github you create your own parallel repository.

Github uses "pull requests" on the original project to allow you to request those with commit rights to pull changes from your fork.

Comment: Yes, I think I got that. I have my own fork, my fork is connected to upstream, I fetch upstream so my wc is aware of changes done there, then I create a new branch in my fork, but off of upstream's latest checkin. I push to my fork, then create a pull request. It is this pull request that is problematic, since it includes a conflict with changes done to upstream/master after I branched off of it.

Comment: Then you need to merge in the changes done upstream and make the code work correctly and _then_ create the pull request.  This is actually a very good thing, as it puts the burden on the submittor instead of the merger.

Comment: So you're not supposed to rebase in this case..?

Comment: Rebase makes the git tree prettier and it is good to do it if  the maintainer merges you branch simply. He can also decide  to squash it into one commit. But since it is the maintainer decision, you should provide him a proper rebased branch.

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier could you expand on that (in an answer), preferably with the steps needed to "provide him a proper rebased branch"?