# GitLab not able to sync fork

Tags: gitlab

I recently installed GitLab, however, I can't figure out how to use forks properly. I have the following versions installed:

```
GitLab 7.7.1
GitLab Shell 2.4.1
GitLab API v3
Ruby 2.1.4p265
Rails 4.1.1
```

I have found out the URL for forks (by creating another user and adding it to the project, but it doesn't show up in the GUI on own projects, link `http://server.com/<user>/<repo>/fork/new` works though), and once a fork has been made, it is not possible to sync the fork. At least, there's nothing I can find on Google nor the documentation for GitLab, but it is mentioned in changelogs at places or issues that apparently have been accepted (can't find the source anymore though).

Can anyone explain me how forking works and how I can sync the fork once the original repository has been updated?

Comment: My organisation has a customised version of GitLab that disallows mirroring, but this article looks promising for setting up hourly syncing. If anybody gets this working then feel free to submit it as an answer. https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/12/01/how-to-keep-your-fork-up-to-date-with-its-origin/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how I can sync the fork once the original repository has been updated?

Simply by adding a remote reference to the original repo: see "[Pull new updates from original Github repository into forked Github repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".

The opposite (from fork to original repo) is done using **merge request**: see "[GitLab Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)"