# git fetch upstream doesn't work

Tags: git

I'm trying to use `git fetch upstream master` to get the latest commit from another user's repository. But unfortunately that doesn't work. I have also tried `git fetch upstream`.

What does work is `git pull upstream master`, but I don't want to use that all the time, because that will always automatically perform a merge.

This is the output that I get when I execute `git fetch upstream master`:

```
git fetch upstream master
From https://github.com/jchun/nodeSite
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

And here are my remotes:

```
git remote -v
origin git@github.com:superzaky/nodeSite.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:superzaky/nodeSite.git (push)
upstream       https://github.com/jchun/nodeSite.git (fetch)
upstream       https://github.com/jchun/nodeSite.git (push)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fetch did work, but to see the result, you should do a:

```
git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate --branches
```

You would see the upstream branches (including the upstream/master)

You can also check the latest SHA1 fetched with:

```
git branch -avv
```

The `git pull upstream master` didn't repeat the fetch part (since it was already done), but merge as well `upstream/master` to `master`.

Comment: Ah yes your first command did work, the second command didn't work unfortunately. Here is a screenshot of it link: http://i.imgur.com/EejCCF5.png

I still got a question: the fetch did work, but how can I now update my repository  with the latest commits from the user's repository?

Comment: @superkytoz yes, it was `git branch` (I have it aliased to `git br`). In order to update your fork, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309: you `git rebase upstream/master` your own master branch, and then push to your fork.

Comment: Why doesn't `git log --pretty=oneline` show the upstream commits?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky upstream means you need the `--all` option