# Sync my fork with the original repo on github?

Tags: github, git-clone

I have forked a repo on my github. And I also cloned my fork on my desktop like this

```
git clone myfork.git
```

and did some commits. How do I keep my fork in sync with the the original repo with my latest commits?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've formatted your question. Please confirm it  still asks what you need. Revert otherwise.

Comment: maybe https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ helps

Comment: There is a cli tool available to do this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/upfork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you commit, you should `git fetch upstream`, which will get the changes from the parent repository. After this, you should `git checkout master`, which will move you back to your fork's `master` branch. The parent repository's changes are held in the `upstream/master` branch, so you can `git merge upstream/master` to merge the parent repository's changes into your current fork. This will update your repository, and repeat whenever you want to pull the latest changes from the parent repository.

As stated in the comments, you can use https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ for more help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already cloned the repository. Now, add your original repository, for convention lets name it **original** repository. Same as above, Copy-URL of your **authors original repository**

```
git remote add original COPY-URL
```

If you successfully added the remote repository. Now lets fetch that, we are actually pullinig the original here:

```
git fetch original
```

Since we fetched the original. Lets merge them

```
git merge

git merge original/master
```

[How do I update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository)

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository?rq=1) for more details: