# Git Merge with Remote Master

Tags: git, github, merge

I've contributed to many open source projects. Typically, as external contributors don't have write access to the repository they contribute to, the workflow is as follows:

1. Fork the repo and `clone` a private copy
2. `git checkout -b feature-branch` on the forked repo
3. Push commits to this branch
4. Open a pull request to merge `local:feature-branch` into `remote:master`

This is all fine, but I've recently ran into a problem when there is a merge conflict forcing me to merge `master` into my feature branch so the pull request can be accepted.

The command would typically be:

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout feature-branch
git merge master
```

But when I go through these steps, `git` displays `Already up-to-date.`, which makes sense. Because I'm in a forked version of the repo, my copy will never be able to get the recent remote changes to `master`.

So it looks like because I'm working on a forked copy that can't be merged, my PR is forever un-mergable.

How can I fix his problem?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository) what you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps, but I feel like this workflow is so common there should be other steps around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The command would typically be:
>
> ```
> git checkout master
> git pull origin master
> git checkout feature-branch
> git merge master
> ```

Well, the problem would be there on the 2nd line.

```
git pull origin master
```

The `origin` remote is set to your fork.  If you run something like

```
git remote show origin
```

something like

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/repo.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/YOUR-NAME/repo.git
  HEAD branch: master
```

will show up.

That being said, you have to pull from the forked remote. Run

```
git remote show
```

which will show all of the remotes.

Checkout to your master branch and then run

```
git pull <the-remote-that-isnt-origin> master
```

where `<the-remote-that-isnt-origin>` is the remote that shows up that isn't `origin` when you run `git remote show`.

Now, most open source projects don't like merge commits, so I suggest [**rebasing**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

```
git checkout your-branch
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1):

What you'd have to do is merge `master` of the remote repo into your `feature-branch` so your branch is up-to-date with the remote `master`, not your own `origin` master.

```
git checkout feature-branch
git pull remote master
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I was thinking. Which is bad because I don't control the remote repo. And, worse yet, the owners of the repo don't own my fork. So the merge can never happen.

Comment: The fact that you can fork it in the first place means you have at least read access to it, which means you can pull from their master. 
`git remote add theirs git@github.com:their/repo.git`
`git pull theirs master`