# Git - can I determine from the command line where a forked repo was forked from?

Tags: git, github

I've got a forked github repo on my machine, I'll call `MYFORK`.

It was forked from a repo I'll call `MAIN_REPO`

Is there a generic way from the command line to find out where `MYFORK` came from? ie the answer should be `MAIN_REPO`, not the url to my fork on github.

I'm open to git or command line github specific solutions, and am interested in solutions that don't require me to have manually added an "upstream" at some point, [as implied here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/26510).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of work, but you could probably use e.g. [octokit.rb](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) or the [github_api gem](https://github.com/piotrmurach/github) to write a small Ruby script that accesses the GitHub API to list all your repositories, searching for the one whose `url` field matches your `origin` remote, and for that object again look at the `parent` object's `url` field. That gives you the repository your repository was forked from. If you're interested in the ultimate source of all forks of forks, use the `source` object's `url` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your repo may have multiple "remotes" to sync changes from. You can list them with `git remote -v`.
Sure, if your "fork" repo on the github, you will see only your fork in the "remotes" list, and there is no generic method to find "original" repo, except using github own api.