# Maintaining a branch that syncing with upstream

Tags: git

I'm planning to add some code based on a project on github, e.g. add some customerized options that fit my project.

One idea is to fork and create a branch to include all my changes. Every time upstream has new changes, I fetch and rebase them to my branch.

Suppose these are my remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
my   git@github.com:khing/myproject.git (fetch)
my   git@github.com:khing/pyproject.git (push)
up   https://github.com/upstream/project.git (fetch)
up   https://github.com/upstream/project.git (push)
```

upstream has three commits: A, B, C, and I have two extra commits: M, N

So I guess current branches will be like:

```
up: A--B--C
my: A--B--C--M--N
```

Suppose upstream has two new commits D and E, I should fetch and rebase (and yes, I might have to fix merge conflicts), so I guess it will be:

```
up: A--B--C--D--E
my: A--B--C--D--E--M--N
```

Is this a good way maintaining my own branch while keeping up-to-date with an upstream branch?

Comment: Fetch is good but I don't think you will need to rebase. Otherwise it is all good. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is what I described in "[Pull new updates from original GitHub repository into forked GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/6309)".

Since that answer (2010), you can:

- configure to always pull from the original upstream repo

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/upstream/project.git
  git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:khing/myproject.git
  ```
- make sure you always rebase your local commits on top of what is fetched:
  (needs Git 2.9+, June 2016, see "[Can “`git pull`” automatically stash and pop pending changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309)")

  ```
  git config pull.rebase true
  git config rebase.autoStash true
  ```

Then a simple `git pull` is enough.