# How to sync forked repository without creating a new commit

Tags: git, github

I created a [PR](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/4426/) for [this](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/4365) issue, after a while the main repository is updated with new accepted PRs and my fork is behind the main repository.

So now I tried to [synchronize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3903835/3734690) my Forked Repositoy, but that's not the end of the problem I have to sync my [commit](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/pull/4426/commits/591f75290c676fb0509d9e73e72cf66e4af291e5)s or log with the main repository.

How do I synchronize my forked repository time-line/logs with the main repository.

Comment: Probably with a rebase on top of upstream/master. I am commuting right now, and on my phone. I will answer when I get back.

Comment: Oh okay...The problem is with the updated commits, they are glued into a single commit, which appears as a single commit(combo of 10 or more commits) in fork log. I just want to avoid re-fork, maybe separating each commit from the single 'merge' commit would work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is with the updated commits, they are glued into a single commit, which appears as a single commit(combo of 10 or more commits) in fork log

That is expected, since you have pulled (fetch+*merge*)

I would advise you to locally remove to remove that merge commit, and rebase (ie replay your commits) on top of `upstream/master` (with `upstream` being the remote name for the original repo)

Plus, I would have isolated those changes in a dedicated branch, but since you have started the PR from `master`, let's stay on `master`.

Make sure you don't have any local work in progress.

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add upstream <Repository URL>
```

Check the output of `git remote -v`: you should see `upstream` and `origin`, with origin referencing your fork.

```
git log # make sure master HEAD is at the right commit
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
# test if everything is still working
git push --force
```

Comment: Is it going to affect my PR commit as that commit is more costly than all of this

Comment: @ChinmayaB No it will not: the `push --force` will re-upload your commits, and the PR in progress will automatically update itself with those new commits.

Comment: @ChinmayaB All you need to do before pushing (push --force) is make sure you do see locally your commits on top of the upstream repo up-to-date. If what you see is correct, and working, you can push --force to your fork, and the PR will take that into account automatically.

Comment: Git is not able to get upstream repository it says...`fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
`

Comment: @ChinmayaB Sorry, I assumed you had upstream already. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: No I've had an upstream I followed your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository/3903835?noredirect=1#comment76154945_3903835

Comment: @ChinmayaB Well, I have edited the answer anyway: check if the command I have added will help

Comment: I used `git reset` command and now I cannot retrieve my old commit!

Comment: If you have committed, they're not lost:  see git reflog

Comment: You can create a new branch at that sha1, and you will see your commits there

Comment: The `rebase` command manages the rewinding and putting new comments. The problem was created due to the `reset` you should remove that from answer. `rebase` will automatically perform reset and then again rebase operations.