# How do I keep a fork of a branch in sync with the actual branch while also keeping the edits I made to the fork?

Tags: github

There is a library with a branch named `dev` which I created a fork of [here](https://github.com/LordKanelsnegle/Discord.Net). I then made a commit to my fork so that it would better suit my needs, and I intend to make further commits in the future. However, as the library is still in development I would also like my fork to stay up to date with the changed made in the original `dev` branch so that it has all of the latest bugfixes and such. Is it possible to sync the two branches while keeping my personal changes?

Edit:
I've looked at the possible duplicate and it seems like an appropriate answer but I just want to clear up one thing before I accept it - I need to sync to just the `dev` branch and not the whole repo, so would I do `git rebase upstream/dev`? What does `git rebase upstream/master` even do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull new updates from original GitHub repository into forked GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to periodically [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) your fork. Alternatively, you could merge the changes in if you'd like to preserve the history.