# Github repository merge explained

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am forking from an existing repository, call it Source. I make my own private repository where I make changes to some files and merge it to my own Github repo. However, every now and then the Source repo makes updates to some of the 'core' files. Is there anyway I can have both my private repo and the original source repo as remote sources and update my local files as the source is updated and push to my private repo as I make changes for my self?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull new updates from original GitHub repository into forked GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903817/pull-new-updates-from-original-github-repository-into-forked-github-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+forked+repo

Answer (score 1):

You have a `forked` repository and you wish to keep your fork updated with the changes in the `source` or `upstream` repository.

GitHub has a step-by-step help to pull changes from the original upstream repo [here](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork/) and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).

To sync your fork with the upstream:

1. Change the current working directory to your local project
2. Fetch the branches and their respective commits from the upstream repository. Commits to `master` will be stored in a local branch, `upstream/master`

   > $ git fetch upstream
3. Check out your fork's local master branch.

   > $ git checkout master
4. Merge the changes from `upstream/master` into your local `master` branch. This brings your fork's `master` branch into sync with the upstream repository, without losing your local changes.

   > $ git merge upstream/master