# How to re-work on the forked GitHub repository after merge?

Tags: git, github

I had forked a repository few months ago. I made some modifications on development branch and made a pull request, which was merged later to repo from which it was forked.

Now I want to make some more modifications, but the repository from which I had forked has many updates.

I need those updates in the forked repo in my GitHub account. I tried doing all the below steps:

```bash
$ git clone git@github.com:rupali/jira-plugin.git

$ cd jira-plugin && \
git remote add jira-upstream git@github.com:jenkinsci/jira-plugin.git

$ git fetch jira-upstream

$ git merge jira-upstream/master
```

But still I cannot see any changes in the forked repository in my account. It still shows the same commit which was present few months before.

No clue where I am making mistake. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Merging between forks in GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you merged `jira-upstream/master` to your local `master` branch, if you want to see those changes reflected in your remote origin repo on GitHub, then you need to push the updates there like this:

```
$ git push origin master
```

This assumes that you have `git@github.com:rupali/jira-plugin.git` set up as the `origin` remote, which it should be based on your `clone` command in your question.

Comment: Thanks I got the recent changes from the repository forked to my repository :)