# Merging between forks in GitHub (with branchs)

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, remote-branch

The question is similar to [Merging between forks in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github).
However, my problem is that I want to merge remote branch in the remote repository.

I have been trying to:

```
git pull <remote_repository>/<remote_branch> master
```

or

```
git pull <remote_repository>:<remote_branch> master
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Thanks Jubobs, good job.

Answer (score 0):

My jobmate says the solution.

It is:

git pull <remote_name> <remote_branch>