# How can I share code with a Freelancer and easily merge it back afterwards?

Tags: git, git-merge

I would like to share my code with a freelancer, but without access to a couple of files and the git history. If I delete those files and the history, how can I easily merge everything back afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize a branch with which the freelancer has access.

From there, you could frequently merge his commits into your production or development branch.

I'm not sure if Github supports this functionality, but I know that Bitbucket allows administrators to create user groups that have access to certain branches.

[Here is the documentation for said functionality.](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/)

Comment: That's for write restrictions. Does a branch not have read-access to previous code?

Comment: I think I need to see how to treat code from a different git repo like a branch.

Comment: You could work with forks, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github) an existing post about merging between forks

Comment: Forks keep history. I think I'll need to merge 2 separate projects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040958/merge-two-git-repositories-without-breaking-file-history/