# Merge different source repositories occasionally

Tags: git, github

I'm new using git. Let's suppose that I have forked a repo "my-repo" from another user called "user-repo".

This repo is very active. My repository has a lot of changes and I am not planning to make a pull request, but handle "my-repo" as an independent repository. Is there a way to pull from the "user-repo" changes and merge to "my-repo" to later push to "my-repo" ?

Comment: Thank you to all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you have non-committed changes, a pull is not allowed. So, there are two options that you can try
2. You can stash your changes, so that your branch is clean - do a pull from "user-repo" and then un-stash your changes. When you stash your changes, all changes you do are reverted and saved at a different location, thus making the working branch clean. Read more [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)
3. You can commit changes in your branch and then do a pull from "user-repo" and once the pull is done, you can proceed further.