# git merging changes to local branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to merge changes from a central repo to a local branch without having to commit/stash the edits on the local branch and checkout master?

If I am working on local branch "work" and there are some uncommited changes, I use the following steps to get updates from the central repo into my working branch.

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull 
git checkout work
git rebase master
git stash pop
```

Usually there are no uncommitted changes in "work" and then I omit the stash steps.

What I would really like is something like the following:

```
git pull master  (updates master while work branch is checked out and has changes)
git rebase master (rebases the updates into work branch uncommited changes are still safe)
```

Is there something easier than what I currently do?

Comment: it amazes me that this is still so hard to do in Git. as a long-time SVN user, this built-in functionality (seemlessly merging remote changes into a modified working copy) is something that my team relied on daily.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do (on branch `work`):

```
git stash
git pull --rebase origin master
git stash apply
```

`git pull --rebase` both pulls remote changes and rebases your local changes on top of the remote ones.  I.e. essentially does what you show in your script.

Local changes, of course, should be committed or stashed on `merge` or `rebase` (because if merge conflict happens, conflicting changes should be uncommitted for you to resolve them--but where would your local changes go then?)

When you later decide to update `master` and to merge `work` branch with it, it won't cause problems, since changes pulled are the same.  So you don't have to update `master` when you pull changes.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel and @Pran.  This works, what I needed to realize is it was not neccesary to update master at this point.  It will be updated when work is merged into master.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can pull if you have uncommitted changes.

Therefore, you could do something along the lines of:

```
git stash
git pull --rebase <remote> <branch> # Calls rebase instead of merge.
git stash pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe things have changed since 2010, but **you can pull from a remote even if you have uncommited changes**. Your local changes will stay uncommitted, so you can diff or merge them at your leisure.

```
git pull origin master
```

Tested with git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14276084/303101)