# git & fast-forward updates

Tags: git, github

I'm still new to git and github... well, I forked a plugin on github and made a few changes a while back. The owner added some of my changes, but github didn't show that my changes were merged. Since that time, a few other users have forked and updated the plugin.

Today I downloaded the latest forked version (not yet merged into the master), made my changes and tried to save them to my repository. The push was rejected and I got a "non-fast-forward" updates are rejected. Merge the remote changes...". Well then I did something really stupid - I deleted my github repository and forked the latest branch.

Now if I try to push I get the same error. I've reinitialized my git `git init` and tried to pull from the master `git pull {name} master` (from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867831/merge-changes-from-remote-github-repository-to-your-local-repository)) and I get a "fatal: ... git-pull cannot be used without a working tree". I've also tried the commands from [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github) and get the same error.

Is there anything I can do to fix this and push the lastest version?

Edit: Oops I used `git pull` not `git remote add...`

Comment: "Reinitialize" with `git clone`, not `git init` + `git pull`, and if you use `git init` don't use `--bare`: working repository on your machine should be not bare

Comment: @Jakub Thank you, I think this was part of my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reject with non fast forward means that your local repository is not up to date and that you will have to do a merge locally before you can push again. You have to pull first.

Comment: Try `git fetch`, then compare the output of `git log master` and `git log origin/master`. If the history looks the same, double-check that the SHA-1's on each commit are the same.

Comment: @Amber: Thanks, I see I have two commits (should only be one) with different SHA-1's. I tried using `git rebase --abort` but I got the same "without a working tree" error.

Comment: You may want to save your changes somewhere outside your clone (via `git diff` or similar) and then just nuke your entire clone, re-clone, and re-apply your changes (`git apply`); it seems that your `git init` may have wiped out Git's knowledge that your current working directory is actually a checkout.

Comment: Thanks for your help! @Amber Thanks again, I basically just deleted everything and started over and finally got it working!