# Local, Testing and Production version control

Tags: testing, version-control, versioning, live

I am very new to **version control** and I would like some help if possible.

I was wondering, which is the best way of controlling 3 development environments: **Development > Testing > Production**

- **Development**(Localhost environment) - all the work developed is being done here before any upload

  - Every1 working on the specific project should have a clone of this folder (*each collaborator with its user*, if possible) and every push by user will be sent here, to development folder.
- **Testing** - Should be a clone folder that contains data pushed by **Development** and which is automatically synced with the subdomain `testing` using ftp, or whatever protocol.
- **Production** is the live site, where the stable updates are released.

  - Should it be a clone of **Testing**, or testing upon push should upload the data here?

How about conflict problems when a user pushes a file/s different from what other user pushed 1 minute ago? Of course there can be the task separation and each to do certain things but what if not, what if X commits submit.php and Y also commits submit.php 1 minute before?

What version control software will be most suited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you translate that in term of a DVCS ([Distributed Version Control System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917)), [like Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995636/popularity-of-git-mercurial-bazaar-vs-which-to-recommend/995799#995799), each of your "folders" can be an actual clone of your code repository.

That means that you:

- would push from your local development to '`development`' repo
- would push from '`development`' to '`testing`' (or better yet, have a task on 'testing' in charge of *pulling* '`development`' and trigger some tests if any new commit is detected
- would push from '`testing`' (if tests are ok) to production

Plus you wouldn't accept non [fast-forward update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382820/git-fast-forward-updates) to remote repo, which means any conflict would be first solved locally, before being pushed.

Answer (score 1):

Git is awesome if you have a large team, but IMHO Subversion (SVN) is easier to learn and still provides a good set of core features that will handle your requirements.  A common approach to handling the needs you mention above is to create a subversion repository with three folders called 'trunk', 'branches' and 'tags'.

- **Development**: Happens in the 'trunk' subdirectory.
- **Pre-release testing**:  Happens in an intelligently named subdirectory of 'branches' e.g. 'RC1-test'
- **Stable-release maintenance**: Happens in a version-tagged subdirectory of 'tags', e.g. '2.0'

Basically, all these subdirectories are forks off of your trunk which you can create via the SVN export command.