# Pull in changes from a Github fork

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-commit

Someone forked a Github project of mine and made some changes. How can I merge the changes back in to my upstream version?

Also, is it possible to pull in just a specific commit?

What I'm looking is if there is a way to pull a specific commit instead of the entire branch.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867831/merge-changes-from-remote-github-repository-to-your-local-repository

Comment: That's asking to pull into the fork, not into the upstream (although it's probably the same method?). I'm also curious to know if there is a way to pull a specific commit instead of the entire branch.

Comment: correct, the same applies to the inverse. Oh true, the specific commit part is correctly answered by @Dustin.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Pulling in a single commit would be a cherry-pick and would rewrite the commit ID (and mark you as the committer while retaining the author).  The process is pretty straightforward, though:

```
git fetch git://github.com/user/project.git
git cherry-pick <SHA-COMMIT-ID>
```

You get the SHA from the repository log, for example:

```
git log --oneline

b019cc0 Check whether we have <linux/compiler.h>.
0920898 Include <linux/compiler.h> before including <linux/usbdevice_fs.h>.
cbf0ba1 Add DLT_DBUS, for raw D-Bus messages.
77ed5cd Libnl 2.x returns its own error codes, not errnos; handle that.
```

With `git cherry-pick 0920898` you bring the respective commit to your current branch.

Comment: what's the "commit-to-cherry-pick"? I don't know what belongs there ... is it a url, or some other type of identifier?

Comment: nevermind, I figured out that it's the hash of the commit. Thanks!

Comment: the hash of the commit, or any other way of referring to it, such as "HEAD~2" if it was two commits back from where HEAD currently is.

Comment: You may need to include the fork's branch name: `git fetch git://github.com/user/project.git branchname`

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome tool which is called [hub](https://github.com/github/hub), which provides useful tools to clean up pull requests and generally "helps you win at git".

One useful command in this context is:

`git am -3 <url>`

This allows you to grab the changes from a url and apply its commits/changes to your current local git without even fetching the remote repository (which comes in handy with large repositories).

If you use this command with the git webpage of the commit you want to grab, you end up with this commit in your git. Even more useful: the commit author is kept and not replaced by you (as it would if you use `git rebase`). If you push this to your repo, the changes will be committed by **you**, but authored by the original author.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the /forkqueue on github.
There you can merge commits to your fork.

Or go to the tab "Network" and select "Forkqueue"

Comment: Since then fork queue has been removed. https://github.com/blog/1091-spring-cleaning