# Pull changes Github to Github

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a Github repository.

1. I make a clone of the original.
2. I fork the Github repository to make a second repository.
3. I make a change to the clone of the original.  Push those changes to Github.
4. I now want to pull in the changes referred to in step 2 above into the forked repository.

Is this possible with Github (not using git)?

I know that I can add a second remote (the fork) on my cloned repository, and then push changes up there as well ([related answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867831/merge-changes-from-remote-github-repository-to-your-local-repository)), but I am curious if there's an alternate method that Github provides to push changes out to forked copies of your repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it has to be done via Git.

Remember that pulling a remote involves merges and potentially conflict resolution as well, so in order to pull/merge/push between repos, you need access to Git's merge/conflict resolution machinery. There's no point in Github exposing its own (inevitably complex) interface for it, since you might as well just do it locally via Git.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the insight.