# Forked a SVN project to GitHub, project now moved to GitHub. Possible to merge?

Tags: github, git-svn

I forked a SVN project on GitHub some 2 months ago, using git-svn (git svn rebase), and made my changes, sending some (but not all) via patch files back.

Now the project moved to GitHub, is there any way I can merge these two GitHub projects while keeping my fork's history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the import has been done properly, the SHA1 for the *content* imported on GutHub from SVN should be the same than the SHA1 generated by your git-svn fork on GitHub.

If that is the case, then "[Merging between forks in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123344/merging-between-forks-in-github)" is your answer (or "[Merge changes from remote GitHub repository to your local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867831/merge-changes-from-remote-github-repository-to-your-local-repository)").

If not, it is best to recreate your fork from the official GitHub repo, and re-apply your work as patches on top of said new fork.

Comment: Merging between forks almost worked, but there were lots of conflicts, ended up applying all patches on a new fork.