# How do I back out a series of changes without screwing up history in git

Tags: git

I want to undo some changes without removing them from the history, in a group-friendly way. Currently, I have this (* indicates master):

```
[rev 1] -- [rev 2] -- [rev 3] -- [rev 4] -- [rev 5] -- [*rev 6]
```

I want to get back to rev 2, but in a way that makes sense. I believe it should look like this:

```
[rev 1] -- [rev 2] -- [rev 3] -- [rev 4] -- [rev 5] -- [rev 6] -- [*rev 7]
               |                                                   |
               \---------------------------------------------------/
```

Where rev 7 is the merge of 6 and 2 (and the "merge" is really just "blindly keep rev 2"). No new heads are created. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Branch `rev 2` and then you can merge it back into `trunk (rev 6)` right away.

Comment: I would think about why I wanted to make my project history misleading.  Just create a branch for rev6 and reset master to rev 2.

Comment: @js1568 That leaves me with [rev 6] still considered 'master' and [rev 7] as the new branch. How do I convert [rev7] to be the master instead?

Comment: @antlersoft good idea. Maybe I will end up doing that instead. But I'd still like to know how to do this in git...

Comment: @antlersoft Ah. Here is the concern: If the new master doesn't have the old master as an ancestor, won't everyone else get screwed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would

```
git branch temp
git reset --hard rev2
git reset --soft temp
git add -A
git commit -m "this commit makes all the changes so that the tree at rev7 looks like the tree at rev2"
git branch -d temp
```

There is a good post by Scott Chacon about the modifiers (hard, soft and mixed) on the reset command and others.

without a temp branch, you could:

```
git reset --hard rev2
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
git add -A
git commit -m "this commit makes all the changes so that the tree at rev7 looks like the tree at rev2"
```

If you want a merge there, you could just:

```
git merge --no-ff -s ours rev2
```

(careful, this is different than the recursive strategy with the "ours" option)

Comment: Thanks. After-the-fact, I also found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git which is related but has a different strategy (although somewhat different because he _needed_ to merge, unlike me)