# Force my local master to be origin/master

Tags: git, github, branch

I've let master and origin/master get stuck in the sidelines, and am no longer interested in the changes on that branch.

I followed these instructions to get my local master pointing to the right place
[Make the current git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git)

```
 git checkout better_branch
 git merge --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
 git checkout master
 git merge better_branch             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

which worked fine except git status gives

```
C:\data\localprojects\Beko2011Azure [master]> git status

# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 395 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

so how do I now persuade origin/master (github) to reflect my master. Anything orphaned on origin/master can be safely abandoned.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

To have `origin/master` the same as `master`:

```
git push -f origin master:master
```

Discussion on the parameters:

- `-f` is the **force** flag. Normally, some checks are being applied before it's allowed to push to a branch. The `-f` flag turns off all checks.
- `origin` is the name of the remote where to push (you could have several remotes in one repo)
- `master:master` means: push my local branch `master` to the remote branch `master`. The general form is `localbranch:remotebranch`. Knowing this is especially handy when you want to delete a branch on the remote: in that case, you push an empty local branch to the remote, thus deleting it: `git push origin :remote_branch_to_be_deleted`

A more elaborate description of the parameters could be found with [`man git-push`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

---

**Opposite direction:** If you want to throw away all your changes on `master` and want to have it exactly the same as `origin/master`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

If `git checkout -B master origin/master` is not working for you (when you do `git pull` your local `master` are still stuck on an older `origin/master` branch), you can try this:

```
git remote prune origin

git pull
```

It should reset your local `master` to track the latest `origin/master`.