# Reverting a series of pushed merges and commits in Git (without rewriting history)

Tags: git, git-revert

## Context

One of my teammates mistakenly pushed some commits to our main development branch. We're a small, collocated team. Our remote repository is hosted on an internal server.

Here is the top of our commit log (all these commits have already been pushed):

```
$ git log develop -6 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
faada93 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
244d174 Support classes again
a97a877 Pruned all unused references (again).
8c29252 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
a78b993 Support models & methods - product types & categories
da8b496 Resolved JIRA issue PPF-182
```

`da8b496` is the last commit we wanted to keep in our `develop` branch, so we needed to revert the 5 last commits. We created a new branch from `8c29252` to continue work in a "feature branch."

I tried many things, guided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217372/195964) and [this post from Linus](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt), and ended up doing what you can see in my Terminal history below. But I'm not sure if what I ended up doing is "the right way." The information I found was complex; I was unable to discern a "best solution" for this particular problem.

## Question

Was the approach I chose (see details below) a good way to revert those 5 commits, without harming our history? Is there an easier or "more correct" way to accomplish the same thing?

Amongst other things, I considered creating a new branch from `da8b496` (`git checkout -b new-develop da8b496`) and abandoning our current `develop` branch, but that just didn't feel right.

---

## What I ended up doing (details)

First, I created a new branch for the commits `a78b993` and `8c29252`, because these commits contain work that we want to keep and eventually merge back to our main development branch.

```
$ git checkout -b new-feature-brach 8c29252
```

Then I started reverting the offending commits in our development branch.

I tried this first, but it didn't work (likely because some of the commits are merges):

```
$ git revert a78b993..HEAD
error: a cherry-pick or revert is already in progress
hint: try "git cherry-pick (--continue | --quit | --abort)"
fatal: revert failed
```

So… I manually reverted each commit instead; one by one:

```
$ git revert -m 1 faada93
[develop 40965a5] Revert "Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git"
8 files changed, 167 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

$ git revert 244d174
[develop 3cebd68] Revert "Support classes again"
45 files changed, 557 insertions(+), 1572 deletions(-)
(list of affected files)

$ git revert a97a877
error: could not revert a97a877... Pruned all unused references (again).
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

$ git mergetool
Merging:
exampleFile1.cs
exampleFile2.cs

Deleted merge conflict for 'exampleFile1.cs':
{local}: deleted
{remote}: modified file
Use (m)odified or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? m

Deleted merge conflict for 'exampleFile2.cs':
{local}: deleted
{remote}: modified file
Use (m)odified or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort? m

$ git commit -m "Adding files to be reverted along with the next commit."
[develop 15bc02b] Adding files to be able to revert the next commit in line.
2 files changed, 239 insertions(+)
(list of affected files here)

$ git revert -m 1 8c29252
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 3 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       exampleFile1.cs.orig
#       exampleFile2.cs.orig
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git revert a78b993
[develop 841e77c] Revert "Support models & methods - product types & categories"
2 files changed, 239 deletions(-)
(list of affected files here)
```

Commit log after all the reverts were done:

```
$ git log develop -10 --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
841e77c Revert "Support models & methods - product types & categories"
15bc02b Adding files to be able to revert the next commit in line.
3cebd68 Revert "Support classes again"
40965a5 Revert "Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git"
faada93 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
244d174 Support classes again
a97a877 Pruned all unused references (again).
8c29252 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
a78b993 Support models & methods - product types & categories
da8b496 Resolved JIRA issue PPF-182
```

Graph after reverts:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline -8 develop
* 841e77c Revert "Support models & methods - product types & categories"
* 15bc02b Adding files to be able to revert the next commit in line.
* 3cebd68 Revert "Support classes again"
* 40965a5 Revert "Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git"
*   faada93 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
|\
| * a97a877 Pruned all unused references (again).
| *   8c29252 Merge branch 'develop' of <our_repo_path>.git
| |\
| | * da8b496 Resolved JIRA issue PPF-182
```

Seems correct to me. Lastly, I remove some backup files that I don't want to keep:

```
$ git clean -fd
(list of affected files here)
```

Current status is clean:

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 4 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

And then I push everything back to the remote:

```
git push origin develop
```

Comment: Please show the output of `git log --graph --oneline develop`. Also, assuming `faada93` is where `develop` got merged in, all you need to do is revert that one commit, and all of its children that don't belong in the current branch will be reverted too, you don't need to revert any of the other ones. What you did looks way more complicated than what was necessary.

Comment: Thanks, @Cupcake - I added the graph to the question. I made some confusing mistakes with the hashes in my questions; I'll correct them now.

Comment: Is this repository public, or does it a private repo shared by a small team? If it's the latter case, is there a reason why you wouldn't just want to hard reset the branch to the point before the merge?

Comment: This is a private repository, hosted on an internal server, used by a small team of developers. Could "hard reset" be used, without adversely affecting our branch history? We're all pretty new to Git and simply felt like reverting was a safer and "more correct" way of doing it. The information we found was bewildering at best, hence this question :)

Comment: I'm in the [Git chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16442/git) if you'd like to join me there so we can discuss your problem real-time. Oh, wait, sorry, that room is actually frozen, let me try something else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34916/discussion-between-leif-and-cupcake)

Comment: On a side note, have you read the [free online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book)? I learned most of what I know about Git from it. I recommend chapters 1-3, and 6-6.5. I also highly recommend learning how to rebase, both interactively and non-interactively. It's arguably the most important tool in Git.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a small co-located team, so communication isn't a problem.  Make the commit history look as it should have looked:

```
git branch -f develop dab4896
git branch newfeature 8c29252
git push -f origin develop newfeature
```

and have everyone refetch.  You're done.

This kind of mistake is one of the reasons to rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, @jthill. What exactly does that last command do, taking 3 branch names? I've already made a branch from `8c29252` a while back and people have already committed and pushed new things to that branch, so I don't want to reset the "newfeature" branch again.

Comment: Thanks! Clean and simple. I did `git branch -f develop da8b496`, `git push -f origin develop` and then asked everyone to do `git fetch`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This only works until your team doesn't setup CI/CD on develop branch. In other words, If your develop branch is used outside that repository, Don't use `force push` otherwise very confusing happening will come

Answer (score 16):

Even though your history has changed, you can create branches that let you go back and experiment. [Git means never having to say, “you should have.”](http://tomayko.com/writings/the-thing-about-git) If you converge on a reality you like better, then go with it. Otherwise, throw it away.

The examples below will create new branches that leave everything else in your repository alone.

### Alternative 1: git revert

First create a scratch branch at the point where you started your adventure.

```
$ git checkout -b tmp-revert faada93
```

By specifying a commit range, [`git revert`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) will undo multiple commits.

```
$ git revert da8b496..faada93
```

### Alternative 2: git commit-tree

Consider the diagram below from [Git Internals — Git Objects](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects), section 10.2 in the second edition of [*Pro Git*](https://book.git-scm.com/book) by Scott Chacon and Ben Straub. The topmost commit (“third commit”) has a SHA1 hash that begins `1a410e`. In the context of this history, `1a410e^{tree}` would resolve to `3c4e9c`, that is, the tree object immediately to the third commit’s right.

[image: Git Object Graph, Figure 151 from *Pro Git*]
**<sup>Figure 151 from [*Pro Git*](https://book.git-scm.com/book), 2nd ed.</sup>**

Study this model to understand how git tracks *content*. Creating a new fourth commit whose tree is identical to the second commit’s (that is, `0155eb`) would add a new commit object that would *share* or “point to” the existing tree and blobs rather than adding new duplicate objects.

Read on to learn how to perform this low-level stitching with [`git commit-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html).

Start by creating another temporary branch to work on.

```
$ git checkout -b tmp-ctree faada93
```

At this point, you want to create a new commit where its tree (that is, the committed code) is identical to that of `da8b496`, the last commit you wanted to keep. This tree is directly addressable in git: `da8b496^{tree}`.

`git commit-tree` is “plumbing,” a low-level command in git—as opposed to “porcelain.” It may feel awkward or unfamiliar to use, but in this case it gives precise control of the result you want.

Create a new unattached commit whose tree is the same as `da8b496`’s and whose parent (`-p`) is the tip of the current branch, `faada93` in your case. Note that `git commit-tree` reads the commit message of the new commit on the standard input, which the command below supplies with the `echo` command.

```
$ echo Revert back to da8b496 | \
    git commit-tree da8b496^{tree} -p $(git rev-parse tmp-ctree)
new-commit-sha1
```

The italicized portion above is not part of the command. It indicates that `git commit-tree` outputs the SHA1 hash of the newly created commit. Knowing the new commit’s SHA1, you can move the branch to that point, *e.g.*,

```
$ git merge new-commit-sha1
```

In the command above, replace *new-commit-sha1* with the output from `git commit-tree`. (You could do the same `git reset --hard new-commit-sha1`, but hard reset is a sharp tool where casual use is best avoided.)

You could roll all of the above into a single compound command.

```
$ git merge --ff-only $(echo Revert back to da8b496 | \
    git commit-tree da8b496^{tree} -p $(git rev-parse tmp-ctree))
```

The `--ff-only` switch to [`git merge`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) is meant to prevent surprises. Your intent is for the new commit to be a fast-forward or a descendant of the current branch head—its immediate child, in fact!

### Cleanup

To delete the temporary branches above, switch to another and fire away, Mr. McManus. Your other branches will be just as you left them.

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git branch -D tmp-revert tmp-ctree
```

The two should be identical, as you can verify with

```
$ git diff tmp-revert tmp-ctree
```

To keep one, merge it into your `develop` branch.

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge --ff-only tmp-ctree
$ git push origin develop
```

Comment: This seems way more complicated than what is necessary, given the built-in commands that already come with current versions of Git. Why not just use a hard reset or a revert?

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Greg. I will need to spend some more time on understanding exactly what that does, before I dare run it. Also, we have some work in a different branch based off of `8c29252`; I updated my question with this information, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks again for this detailed answer, Greg. I will spend some time to study these options and learn more about how they work, especially `commit-tree`. I didn't have enough time to sit down with this right now and needed to get it sorted quickly, due to an upcoming customer presentation, so I went with the other answer. (I don't like running any commands before I fully understand what they do.)

Comment: `commit-tree` for the win! Thanks.

Comment: When running the `git commit-tree` command above, the `echo` command above it is important. I tried skipping that and the command appeared to just hang. This was because it was waiting for a commit message, followed by `Ctrl+D` to finish. Piping the result of `echo` skips this step.

Comment: Why is this so overcomplicated? Reverting changes should be the primary function of versioning system. If it takes so much manual work to accomplish this, then I'd say GIT has failed as the tool for the job. There should be a single command: git revert-to <commit> which restores repository to the state of this commit without rewriting history and let's us stage those new changes.

Answer (score 7):

May I suggest that this could be considered a duplicate of this answer: [Make the current git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git)

Jefromi's excellent solution was:

```
[git branch better_branch <last good commit>]
git checkout better_branch
git merge --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git checkout master
git merge better_branch             # fast-forward master up to the merge
```

Comment: This is by far the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is very risky.

indeed you can revert and delete the commits that you have already pushed to the repo but if someone has already pulled your changes and he has the commitId that you are going to delete, the repo can become "unstable" and git will not be able to handle the pull and pushes since you deleted commit that is now removed from the history.

Do this (revert and delete commit ) only and only if no one has pull this commit yet.

Comment: This is why I eventually chose to just revert the commits normally. Are you saying that the approach that I chose (reverting each commit manually) is risky? I didn't delete any commits; I only reverted them. (Not sure if I understand).