# How to recover my git branch to an appointed commit?

Tags: git, svn, branch

for example: I want to recover to the last 3 commit in remote?

Comment: What do you mean by 'recover'? Do you mean view the code at that particular snapshot, for a past commit?

Comment: I suggest you reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit this question to fulfill the standards of this page.

Answer (score 0):

What you fetch from a remote is the full history of a repo and its branches.

But once fetched, nothing prevents you to reset your branch to 3 commits back:

```
git checkout yourBranch
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

Make sure you don't have any work in progress (they would be erase), and you would have to force your push to the upstream branch:

```
git push -f origin yourBranch
```

This isn't considered a good practice if you have others fetching that same branch from the same remote repo.

The other technique (which doesn't involve rewriting the history) is to **revert**: see for instance "[Reverting a series of pushed merges and commits in Git (without rewriting history)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18082830/6309)"

```
git revert HEAD~3..HEAD
```

That will create a *new* commit which will cancel the last 3. You can push it as usual.