# How to turn a old commit into master and the new ones into new branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

It is similar to [Make the current git branch a master branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2763006) but a bit different.

I have made some commits in master, but now they wont be used, I want to keep them in the future, turning it into a new branch, I want to get a old commit and merge some features (like cherry-pick) and then make this the current master.

```
      .----------E (no branch)
     /          /
----A---B---C---D (master)
```

Version `D` is the current master, and I want `E` to be the one. I am doing this way:

```
git checkout A
git merge --no-commit --no-ff D
# do some changes here
git commit -m 'message for E'
```

This generate a `no branch` commit, I was wondering how to turn this into master and turn `B`, `C` and `D` a new branch.

The difference for the answer above is that I do not want `E` to be the new branch, I want it to be named master, and change the others to a new branch.

Comment: Do you really want `E` to have all the changes from `B-C-D`?

Comment: @alexeyten it is not all of them, but it is boring doing cherry-pick of several commits, it is easier to undo some of them by `git reset file; git checkout file`

Comment: I solved part of the the problem creating a new branch and moving them: `git checkout -b test; git -m master new-feated-issues; git -m test master` now how to do it for the remote issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the post you linked to, this should only be done if you haven't `push`ed `master` anywhere.

First, create a new branch from `master` with `git branch new-branch master`. You should end up with

```
      .----------E (no branch)
     /          /
----A---B---C---D (master) (new-branch)
```

Now, move master to `E` with

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard E
```

Your final network should look something like

```
      .----------E (master)
     /          /
----A---B---C---D (new-branch)
```

Comment: Do you know how to fix the `remotes/origin/master` issue?

Comment: I don't think you'd have that issue if you had used my method :-). Probably the easiest is to edit your repository's `.git/config` file and move the `merge = refs/heads/master` line from `[branch "new-branch"]` to `[branch "master"]`.

Comment: You are right, I did this way and just just `git push` then the `remotes/origin/master` fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

This command will create new branch pointed to `D`.

```
git branch new-branch D
```

This will set you current branch tip to commit `A` while all changes will stay in place:

```
git reset --soft A
# do some changes here
git commit -m 'message for E'
```

These commands will not create merge commit as in your example, but I guess that you don't need it.