# Force merge into master from branch

Tags: git

I have `master` and a branch off of master called `develop`. I made a lot of changes in `develop` branch such that there are a lot of conflicts with `master`. I would like to force merge `develop` into `master` so that `develop` becomes `master`.

Whats the best way to do this in git?

I tried:

```
$git checkout branch
$get push origin master -f
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fully-specified `push` syntax:

```
git push -f origin develop:master
```

Note that you may cause problems for people who have clones of your repo; this kind of history rewriting is generally frowned upon.