# Promote Git branch to master

Tags: git, github

I have a git (and Github) repo with a `master` branch, a `development` branch and several feature branches. Each of the feature branches have been branched off `development` and subsequently merged into `development`.

I'd now like to "promote" `development` to `master`. I don't want to merge these two branches because conflicts may arise. Essentially, `development` is "production ready" and I'd like for `master` to reflect the current state of `development`. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do to the history of `master`?

Comment: Has development also been branched off master (usually the case, but you might have different setup)? If so, what do you want to do with commits after their common ancestor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git

Comment: I'd like to overwrite (maybe extend is the right word) the history of ```master```.  The idea is that all work is done on ```development``` and at regular intervals ```development``` is promoted ```master```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In other words, develop is your new master. The easiest way to do that would be to simply push developer to master:

```
 git push origin origin/development:master
```

This will work if development started from current master. If not, and you don't want to keep the history of the master you can force the push:

```
git push -f origin/development:master
```

The problem with the forced push might arise if there is other work (branches) forked from master. In such case the safest approach would be to do a technical merge as described in the answers to earlier mentioned [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git).

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the team foundation server.  I want to promote a child branch as the trunk branch without losing the history of both branches.  Is there a workaround in TFS to solve this issue.

Comment: @Sachith TFS has nothing to do with git. Creating a new dedicated question might be a good idea for you.

Answer (score 5):

I think that is better to have a merge commit when declaring develop as ready for production, so that you can roll back.

While this is perfectly doable with plain git commands, I have a script to do all the steps: https://gist.github.com/soulrebel/9c47ee936cfce9dcb725

In practice this is what a promote command does:

```
git pull --ff-only         # check we are up to date on our branch
git checkout master        # go the target branch
git pull --ff-only         # check updates there too
git merge develop --no-ff  # merge with a commit
git push                   # push the merge
git checkout develop       # back to develop
```

Comment: Please describe what the script does a little more; otherwise it's a link-only answer that's supposedly bad for stackoverflow

Comment: Show how to do this without the script.

Comment: @AndreaRatto  I'm having the same problem with the team foundation server.  I want to promote a child branch as the trunk branch without losing the history of both branches.  Is there a workaround in TFS to solve this issue.