# In git, are there any issues with naming a branch after a commit id?

Tags: git, git-branch

I run into a detached head state often.  I would like to create a script that, when I run, automatically creates a branch where I am at and names it after the current commit id.  It appears that git will let me do it, but could a branch and commit having the same name lead to any possible ambiguity or side effects with any git commands?

Comment: What is your problem with manually creating a branch?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I don't like having to keep thinking of branch names "whatever1", etc...  As far as not doing it manually, it's for the same reason I like typing `ll` instead of `ls -l` or `uu` instead of `cd ../..`. I just want to type "branch" and it create the branch.

Comment: But surely if you want a branch, it's do make new commits? It would be rather relevant to take the time to find a good branch name that reflects these intended changes, I think? I know it's hard to find good names, but `fix_typo` would be better than `whatever1`.

Comment: @Gauthier, many times yes.  There are sometimes when I'm just using a branch as a stash and/or the branches are short-lived.  It may not be good practice, I don't know.

Comment: @Gauthier, another motivation is seen here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763006/change-the-current-branch-to-master-in-git.  Many times (probably all the time) I plan on doing meaningful development in git, but there is no easy way to check in something and make it the new master - I have to basically create a meaningless branch as an intermediate step when doing what I want to do.  In my mind any commit should be tracked even if I forgot to check out a branch - this is a way for me to do it. I probably just need to get in the git workflow.

Comment: generally, reflog/doubleclick/middleclick (or ^C^V) is a worst case scenario for going back to someplace you forgot.  If you can remember a memorable word or phrase from the commit message, you can use `:/regex_here` to refer to it, that gets you the most recent commit with a match in its message.  So for short-term branches, just don't bother naming them.

Comment: @hek2mgl, also, as I've found out recently, sometimes I have to try 2 or 3 different ways of doing something, or a combination of the two.  So, the branches will be short lived.  I have my commit comment to tell me what it's doing.  Coming up with branch names, to me, is just an unnecessary extra step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It appears that git will let me do it, but could a branch and commit having the same name lead to any possible ambiguity or side effects with any git commands?

If nothing else, it's going to be pretty confusing for *you*. You could always construct a name for the branch that *includes* the commit hash but is still easy to distinguish from an actual hash, like `Branch_6ac738f999`. Using the actual hash by itself seems like a poor plan.

Answer (score 2):

As said by others, don't give an understandable name to a branch is a bad idea and with doing that, you are taking a bad way...

That said, perhaps you could think about creating an alias to create a branch on the current commit, for example:

```
git b my_new_branch
```

And to create it:

```
git config --global alias.b 'checkout -b'
```

More information [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)